# hiveserver2 not working because of log4j2 file

Tags: hive

I want to start hiveserver2 but if I use hive command to start hiveserver2 hive --service hiveserver2 I have this problem:

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console.

the default port is 10000.
hive is running well but still have this problem

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. Connecting to
>   jdbc:hive2:// Connected to: Apache Hive (version 2.1.1) Driver: Hive
>   JDBC (version 2.1.1) Transaction isolation:
>   TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive hive>

how can I add log4j2 configuration?
i m working on windows 8 and apache hive.

Comment: where can I found the log4j2 file and what do I change to start hiveserver2?

Comment: is there any suggestion please !!